# How to use a command line parameter to supply input in subsequent prompt (batch file)

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, pg-dump

I am using batch file to run certain operation in my application. The command I am using does not take password as a parameter instead it prompts for it while running. This is coming in the way of automating this script. I would like to know how I can take password as a parameter and provide to the application when it prompts.

Comment: Depends on 'the command' - which command, and how does it ask the user for entering the password? Reads from Stdin, shows a dialog?

Comment: I am using pg_dump command of postGre SQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reffering to you comment to [Johannes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871477/how-to-use-a-command-line-parameter-to-supply-input-in-subsequent-prompt-batch-f/2871540#2871540), you would need to modify your call to `pg_dump` to something like this:

`echo %3|pg_dump -h %1 -U %2 %4 > %5`

The Problem is that pg_dump doesn't allow you to pass in the password via stdin. That means this solution will not work here.

But as you can read in the docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html), there is the (unsecure) way of providing the password via environment variable `PGPASSWORD`.

So simply modify your batch file like this:

```
...
set PGPASSWORD=%3
pg_dump -h %1 -U %2 %4 > %5
...
```

Comment: Thanks this suffices my immediate requirement